# Child theme style repeated

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I have create child theme with style.css and functions.css, I edit parts style.css in child theme to get best style. But some page have no effect and style.css from child theme repeated with another version.

style.css

```
#masthead {
    top: 0px;
    background: black !important;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(250,105, 0, 1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(250,105,0, 1);
}
```

functions.php

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

[image: child theme style.css repeated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this :

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

Just  try it. i hope is useful.

Answer (score 1):

When developing a child theme the wordpress environment will automatically load the style.css file inside the child theme folder. Thus it is only needed to enqueue the parent style in your functions.php fil

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

Trying to enqueue the style sheet from the child theme here as well will result in wordpress loading the child style.css file twice.

Comment: so the code just load parent style and then child style will load automatic?

Comment: yeah from what I have seen in the past. Even though the official developers guide for child themes on WP says that you should load a child style sheet as well WP will load your child style twice when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

**What you miss is that in your functions.php codesnippet above you failed to name your own parent style.**

In the code you posted in the 4th line from above need customization according to the name of your actual parent style. **So as an example this line**:

```
$parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
```

**should look like this** in case of using Divi:

```
$parent_style = 'divi-style'; // This is 'divi-style' for the Divi theme.
```

To find out what you should put there instead of 'parent-style' in your case, go to your parent theme folder and open the original (or now parent) functions.php, and there search for "wp_enqueue_style". You will find something like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'divi-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), $theme_version );
```

This is in my case where I use Divi theme. Look at the first attribute of the function. That's what you need. An other example: In case Twenty Fifteen the first attribute will be: 'twentyfifteen-style'

So once you found the used tag-name for your parent style update your 4th line accordingly.

Hope it helped.